# Controllers in Symfony PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I have some html button in my Twig template, in what way I can create a controller of the following class to process this button?
input type="button" id="addLink" value="Add" and Controller for this button

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Where's the connection between the button and a Symfony controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example :

`controller` :

```
public function page(Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('button', $request->request->get('token'))) {
        return $this->render('view.twig');
    }

    ... button are clicked ...
}
```

`view.twig` :

```
<form action=" ... PATH ... " method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('button') }}" />
    <button type="submit">
        Click !
    </button>
</form>
```